# Postgres index not used when using BETWEEN inside join

Tags: postgresql, indexing, filter

I have the following table in my database:

```sql
business_db_dev=# \d schedules2
                                          Table "public.schedules2"
   Column    |              Type              | Collation | Nullable |                Default                 
-------------+--------------------------------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------------
 id          | bigint                         |           | not null | nextval('schedules2_id_seq'::regclass)
 monday      | boolean                        |           | not null | 
 tuesday     | boolean                        |           | not null | 
 wednesday   | boolean                        |           | not null | 
 thursday    | boolean                        |           | not null | 
 friday      | boolean                        |           | not null | 
 saturday    | boolean                        |           | not null | 
 sunday      | boolean                        |           | not null | 
 start1      | time(0) without time zone      |           |          | 
 end1        | time(0) without time zone      |           |          | 
 start2      | time(0) without time zone      |           |          | 
 end2        | time(0) without time zone      |           |          | 
 user_id     | bigint                         |           | not null | 
 inserted_at | timestamp(0) without time zone |           | not null | 
 updated_at  | timestamp(0) without time zone |           | not null | 
Indexes:
    "schedules2_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "schedules2_start1_end1_DESC_NULLS_LAST_index" btree (start1, end1 DESC NULLS LAST)
    "schedules2_start2_end2_DESC_NULLS_LAST_index" btree (start2, end2 DESC NULLS LAST)
    "schedules2_user_id_index" UNIQUE, btree (user_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "schedules2_user_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

I also have other tables that I use to do a join with that one (`users` and `strategies`) which I will not post here for brevity, but if it is needed you can just ask and I will update the question with their structures too.

Giving this table, I'm trying to do the following query

```sql
select u.token
from strategies as st
inner join users as u on (st.user_id = u.id)
inner join schedules2 as sc on (st.user_id = sc.user_id)
where st.exchange = 'binance'
      and st.market_pair = 'btc_usdt'
      and st.timeframe = 'five_minutes'
      and st.name = 'stoch_oscillator'
      and st.inputs = '{5,3,3,80,20}'
      and (sc.start1 is null or ('13:00:01'::time between sc.start1 and sc.end1) or ('13:00:01'::time between sc.start2 and sc.end2));
```

Running this query with `explain analyze` I got this result:

```sql
 Nested Loop  (cost=1.27..215.56 rows=16 width=6) (actual time=0.076..6.050 rows=942 loops=1)
   Join Filter: (st.user_id = u.id)
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.98..197.89 rows=17 width=16) (actual time=0.070..3.650 rows=942 loops=1)
         ->  Index Only Scan using unique_strategy_and_user_id on strategies st  (cost=0.69..7.29 rows=80 width=8) (actual time=0.056..1.083 rows=1000 loops=1)
               Index Cond: ((exchange = 'binance'::text) AND (market_pair = 'btc_usdt'::text) AND (timeframe = 'five_minutes'::text) AND (name = 'stoch_oscillator'::text) AND (inputs = '{5,3,3,80,20}'::character varying[]))
               Heap Fetches: 0
         ->  Index Scan using schedules2_user_id_index on schedules2 sc  (cost=0.29..2.38 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=1 loops=1000)
               Index Cond: (user_id = st.user_id)
               Filter: ((start1 IS NULL) OR (('13:00:01'::time without time zone >= start1) AND ('13:00:01'::time without time zone <= end1)) OR (('13:00:01'::time without time zone >= start2) AND ('13:00:01'::time without time zone <= end2)))
               Rows Removed by Filter: 0
   ->  Index Scan using users_pkey on users u  (cost=0.29..1.03 rows=1 width=14) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=1 loops=942)
         Index Cond: (id = sc.user_id)
 Planning Time: 0.834 ms
 Execution Time: 6.130 ms
```

The important part is this one:

```sql
Index Scan using schedules2_user_id_index on schedules2 sc  (cost=0.29..2.38 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=1 loops=1000)
   Index Cond: (user_id = st.user_id)
   Filter: ((start1 IS NULL) OR (('13:00:01'::time without time zone >= start1) AND ('13:00:01'::time without time zone <= end1)) OR (('13:00:01'::time without time zone >= start2) AND ('13:00:01'::time without time zone <= end2)))
```

As you can see, Postgres is using `Filter` to check the values `start1`, `end1`, `start2` and `end2`, but I was expecting that Postgres would use the two indexes I created for this exact condition:

```sql
"schedules2_start1_end1_DESC_NULLS_LAST_index" btree (start1, end1 DESC NULLS LAST)
"schedules2_start2_end2_DESC_NULLS_LAST_index" btree (start2, end2 DESC NULLS LAST)
```

Removing the join with `schedules2` table and its condition basically halves the query time.

So, my question is, why is Postgres using `Filter` instead of my indexes, and how can I change the query or the indexes itself to optimize this query?

Edit: Note that the values used in the query (like `'13:00:01'::time`) are just examples, in my system this can be anything.

Comment: So the query runs in 6 **milli**seconds - how fast do you need it to be?

Comment: As fast as I can get, this query will be executed multiple times per second, so any optimization I can extract is desirable. I'm not a Postgres expert, but as far as I know, using Filter here is not as efficient as an Index Cond, so if I can change it to use the index for some more gains I would consider it a huge success.

Comment: Just to be clear, I'm not saying that changing Filter with an index will result in better performance, maybe Postgres is right in choosing Filter for this case and that is the best plan possible. I'm saying that I don't know actually, and I'm guessing this filter part would be a candidate to be optimized, and if there is a way to further optimize this query, I'm very much interested.

Comment: Avoid the `OR`. Use `-infinity` instead of NULL for missing lower bounds. Change the query into the `UNION` of two queries, thereby avoiding the `OR`.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Index Cond: (user_id = st.user_id)
> Filter: ....
> Rows Removed by Filter: 0
> ```

The index it is already using is already perfect.  It found no extra rows which had to be removed by the filter (or at least, so few that they rounded to zero).  How could that be improved upon by using more indexes?

Comment: Sure, but that is just because of the sample data I'm using, Real-world data would not filter like this, and even if it did would it not have to check each row with the filter anyway to see if it needs to be filtered or not?

Comment: If user_id is nearly unique in your sample, but not nearly so in your real data, then your sampling method is not suitable to the task at hand.  Please show an EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) for the query from your real data.